# std::thread using one core?

Tags: multithreading, c++11

Trying to use VS 2013 C++ with std::threads.  This test object prints, then sleeps, then prints.  Created a vector of them and called them so that up to four are running at a time.

It works as advertised in that four threads are running concurrently but somehow it appears all to be executing in one of eight cores.

Threads is std::atomic declared elsewhere.

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
std::vector< testclass<int> > _vector;
std::vector< testclass<int> >::iterator tc;
int i;

srand( (unsigned)time(NULL) );
threads = 0;
for (i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
    _vector.push_back(testclass<int>(i));
}
tc = _vector.begin();
while (tc != _vector.end()) {
    if (threads < FOUR_THREADS) {
        i = rand() % 5000;
        tc._Ptr->_value = i;
        std::thread t(&testclass<int>::calc, tc._Ptr);
        t.detach();
        tc++;
        threads++;
    }
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: What does `calc` do? How did you determine that only one core is being used? The OS is free to schedule the cores how it pleases, and if there's not much work to do and some are asleep to begin with, it might not bother waking them up.

Comment: redo this test with a lot more work, for example take the square root of 1 giga-elements.

Comment: Two asides: don't you run into undefined behavior once `while` finishes? You still have 4 threads running, apparently pointing at data that gets destroyed when main exits. Aside 2: it's a bit strange peeking into the internals of an iterator like that.

Comment: Ouch - The original calc just slept for a few seconds.  So all the CPU usage was basically overhead of switching threads.  I then changed calc to run the Sieve of Erathothenes (spelling) and bam CPU usage shot up to about 50%.